# This Node doesn't work the way I thought?

Tags: c, struct, malloc

These are the structures that I have defined.

```
typedef struct stud{
    int StudId;
    float GradePt;
}STUDENT;

typedef struct StudentNode{
    STUDENT* stud;
    struct StudentNode* link;
}StudNode;
```

The below is the code in the main function. I just want to create a singly linked list of STUDENT nodes linked together. But My code throws strange output

```
StudNode* stud1;
StudNode* stud2;
stud1=(StudNode*)malloc(sizeof(StudNode));
stud1->stud->GradePt=3.54;
stud1->stud->StudId=4724;
stud1->link=(StudNode*)malloc(sizeof(StudNode));
stud2=(StudNode*)malloc(sizeof(StudNode));
stud2=stud1->link;
stud2->stud->GradePt=3.89;
stud2->stud->StudId=3424;
cout<<stud1->stud->StudId<<" has a grade of "<<stud1->stud->GradePt<<" out of 4"<<endl;
cout<<stud2->stud->StudId<<" has a grade of "<<stud2->stud->GradePt<<" out of 4"<<endl;
```

```
Output:
3424 has a grade of 3.89 out of 4
3424 has a grade of 3.89 out of 4

--------------------------------
Process exited after 1.216 seconds with return value 3221225477
```

Comment: `stud2=stud1->link;` feels like this is causing issue

Comment: I've pulled the C++ tag because it looks like  C++ solutions aren't what you're looking for. May not be the right call since casting the result of `malloc` is a C++ thing, but far less of a C++ thing than `new`.

Comment: `stud1->link=(StudNode*)malloc(sizeof(StudNode));` doesn't look quite right. Less you're going to initialize the node you probably want a sentinel like `stud1->link=NULL` here.

Comment: Recommendation: draw pictures of how you want these nodes linked, then trace through your code following the instructions exactly and see if you can draw the same picture. If you can't, you'll probably see it right away and know what the code did wrong.

Comment: "doesn't work the way I thought", "code throws strange output", "code in the main function" are all unhelpfully vague. Please study and apply [ask], make a [mre], describe the desired output, explain the contrast to the output you get. Apart from that, the coat hanger visualisation might be helpful - generally when it comes to linked lists etc.

Comment: Right after `stud1=(StudNode*)malloc(sizeof(StudNode))`: where does `stud1->stud` point to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StudNode should probably be:

```
typedef struct StudentNode{
    STUDENT stud;                // No more a pointer
    struct StudentNode* link;
} StudNode;
```

Of course later, the access to `stud` has to be changed.

And the following lines have an issue:

```
stud1->link=(StudNode*)malloc(sizeof(StudNode));    // Line 1
stud2=(StudNode*)malloc(sizeof(StudNode));          // Line 2
stud2=stud1->link;                                  // Line 3
```

In the code above, you have a memory leak: `stdu2` get allocated memory on line 2 and immediately after the pointer gets replaced by `stdu1->link` which has been allocated on line 1.

Probably line 1 should be `stud1->link = NULL;`

The code becomes:

```
typedef struct stud{
    int StudId;
    float GradePt;
}STUDENT;

typedef struct StudentNode{
    STUDENT stud;
    struct StudentNode* link;
} StudNode; 

StudNode* stud1;
StudNode* stud2;

// Initialize node 1
stud1=(StudNode*)malloc(sizeof(StudNode));
stud1->stud.GradePt=3.54;
stud1->stud.StudId=4724;
stud1->link=NULL;

// Initialize node 2
stud2=(StudNode*)malloc(sizeof(StudNode));
stud2->stud.GradePt=3.89;
stud2->stud.StudId=3424;
stud2->link=NULL;

// Link node 1 to node 2
stud1->link=stud2;

// Show data
cout<<stud1->stud.StudId<<" has a grade of "<<stud1->stud.GradePt<<" out of 4"<<endl;
cout<<stud2->stud.StudId<<" has a grade of "<<stud2->stud.GradePt<<" out of 4"<<endl;
```

Comment: The problem is solved. But I don't understand why should I not have STUDENT* stud in the declaration of the StudentNode? Can you clarify me on that?

Comment: You *could* have `STUDENT* stud;` in StudentNode but if you do so, you must allocate memory for it in an additional step. Having `STUDENT stud;` is useless and even has the adverse effect of memory fragmentation and slower code due to one more indirection when accessing any STUDENT member.